# Getting a license key error message while importing xlwings in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, xlwings

I am trying to import xlwings in Jupyter Notebook. I ran the command `conda search xlwings` and it shows that xlwings is installed in the setup. However, when I run the code `import xlwings as xw`, i get the below mentioned error

> "couldn't find license key"

Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xlwings 0.19.0 had an error (that was fixed 24h later with 0.19.1) but unfortunately the main conda channel upgraded right in that time. The easiest is to upgrade to the latest version via conda-forge:

```
conda upgrade -c conda-forge xlwings
```